# Dell C1100 Not working with new memory

Tags: memory

I have a Dell C1100 running the latest firmware S99C3B23.

I've recently upgraded the CPU and the ram. I've put in 18x16GB 2Rx4 PC3L-10600R ram in the server and it works fine with the L5520 CPU in the server. When I put in the new X5675 CPU in it just power cycles. With the old ram 18x4GB 2Rx4 PC3-8500R the new CPU works fine. I've also tried clearing the BIOS and that did not seem to make a difference. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Do you have one or two CPUs? Also, you might want to [check the supported memory configurations](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_cloud_products/poweredge-c1100_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf) for that server to see if you're running a supported configuration. Although the mix of the older CPU working and the newer one not is quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

I've put in the old CPU's and went into BIOS and loaded the optimized defaults then replaced the CPU's again and it started working.